# Erro Ao criar tabela no bd com Sequelize | postegres

Tags: sequelize-js

No terminal ao executar o comando `yarn sequelize db:migrate` pra criar a tabela `users` do **GoBarber** no banco de dados, retorna o seguinte erro:

```
yarn run v1.21.1 $ /home/dev/Documentos/GoBarber/node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate

Sequelize CLI Node: 12.14.1, CLI: 5.5.1, ORM: 5.21.4

Loaded configuration file "src/config/database.js". == 20200208221655-create-users: migrating =======

ERROR: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

error Command failed with exit code 1. info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

No **PostBird** em **Info** tenho esse retorno do erro:

```
Type: table

Estimate rows count: 0

Total size on disk: 8 KB (Table: 0 Bytes, Indexes: 8 KB, Toast: 0 Bytes)

Source SQL Loading...
Error happen while running pg_dump: 
    pg_dump: server version: 12.1 (Debian 12.1-1.pgdg100+1);
    pg_dump version: 10.10 (Ubuntu 10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) 
    pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

Algo relacionado a alguma *version*, será que instalei algo errado?

Answer (score 0):

não consegui identificar o erro, mas, fiz uma limpeza no docker com o comando prune Ex.: docker images prune
docker container prune 
e instalei novamente , também refiz a migration users e funcionou.